# Wordpress - How to tell if im on the main page

Tags: php, wordpress

Just wondering how to tell if this is on the main page

```
if (mainpage??) // do
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home